# SQL Slow connection, insert respect select

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with a user id and a date, several users connect at the same time and only one user a day can do insert in the database.

I have a slow connection to the server and what it takes to do the select of the last entry, whether it has been today or not, since it can not be a primary key because the date can vary, sometimes it makes double registrations for the same day.

How can I do this so that this does not happen and I only insure an insert a day?

Thank you

Code:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT MAX(timestamp_pole) as last_pole FROM pole WHERE id_group = ". $id_grup;
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
$resultado = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
$las_00 = date('Y-m-d');
$las_00 = strtotime($las_00);
if ($resultado['last_pole'] >= $las_00){
} else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO pole (timestamp_pole, id_user, id_group) VALUES (". $timestamp .",". $user['id'] .",". $id_group .")";
    $mysqli->query($sql);
    //return addslashes($sql);
    if (isset($user['username']))
        return "@". $user['username'] ." pole!";
    else 
        return $user['name'] ." pole!";
}
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create unique index using `(date, id_group)` as key, by that way you can make sure that there isn't any duplicated date in same group. Also remember to implement try/ catch as running insert query.

Comment: That is not possible because I have a timestamp field and if someone makes an entry at 00:01 and another at 00:02 they have different values